# error: expected expression before 'struct'

Tags: c, struct

I have sample.h having:

```
typedef struct _abcd_header{
    U32     num;   
    U32     page;     
    int     maxDataSize;   
} abcd_header;

struct abcdcommand{
    abcd_header hdr;
    U32 timeout;
};

#define abcCommand _IOWR('m',20, struct abcdcommand)
```

and sample.c having:

```
struct abcdcommand *command;
command = (struct abcdcommand*)malloc(sizeof *command + 1);
memset(command, 0, sizeof *command);

int i = ioctl(10, abcCommand, command); //error: expected expression         before'struct'
```

I am not getting what I am missing. Pls. help thanks in advance.

Comment: you might want to add `#include "sample.h"` to the top of sample.c. Also, is ioctl even a function defined anywhere? maybe you need to add an `#include "stdio.h"` or `#include "stdlib.h"` at the top of sample.c as well.

Comment: is that code in `sample.c` inside a function? What is the "+ 1" for in malloc?

Comment: You should avoid names starting with an underscore, and doubly so names starting with underscore and a capital letter.  What is `_IOWR`? It must be a macro if you can pass `struct abcdcommand` to it.  If it is a function, then you can't call it like that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler _IOWR seems to be a macro in Linux. `#define _IOWR(g,n,t) _IOC(IOC_INOUT, (g), (n), sizeof(t))`

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Ugh; incomplete information as so often (in the question).  Which header, etc, would be a help.  Anyway, it's bedtime (or a quarter past bedtime) here.

Comment: Not sore. I haven't been able to google any good documentation on it, but it just seems to be used as a helper macro by the header to define other macros that are actually part of the device driver API, so perhaps OP shouldn't be using it

Comment: As a side note just do `struct abcdcommand *command = calloc(sizeof *command + 1, 1);`. Initialize instead of assignment, don't cast the return of `malloc`, use `calloc` if you want do initialize anyhow, initialize all of your object and not only a part.

Comment: @Mike, I have kept those headers at the top.

Answer (score 0):

_IOWR seems to be function call. A function call you cannot give a type; you can only give it a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Given your code, I think that you try to define a macro with function like behavior. Given that, in the pre-processor you do not care about types in "arguments".

A good (really good in my opinion) point to get started is the queue definition from linux.

You can have a look at: http://linux.die.net/man/3/queue

Answer (score 0):

> I am not getting what I am missing.

You are missing the definition of the `_IOWR()` macro.

```
#include <linux/ioctl.h>
```

in your `sample.h`.